# Is `std::atof` guaranteed to produce identical output when given identical string input?

Tags: c++, double, unordered-map, atof

I'm reading double values from file as strings and parsing them with `std::atof`. Afterwards, I'm using the values as keys in a unordered map. It's seems to be working correctly, but is it guaranteed to work in 100% of the cases?

I'm asking the question because it's extremely hard to produce identical double value if you do any arithmetic operations with it.

Is `std::atof` guaranteed to produce exactly the same double value if given the same string value multiple times?

Comment: Regardless of what `atof` returns, I wouldn't use floating-point values as keys in a `map`.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title (as well as at the end of the body) is Yes.

Comment: I suspect that question is badly stated and actual problem is [some flavor of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1387438). I suspect that because of this statement: `hard to produce identical double value if you do any arithmetic operations with it`.

Comment: _"[...] if given the same string value multiple times?"_ Do you mean inside the same program? A standard implementation that would behave differently each time you call the function would be really broken. Or do you mean multiple times accross different platforms?

Comment: As @churill has stated - across multiple platforms and/or programs, the "current C locale" could be different - which *could* cause different interpretations of a decimal numeric string.

Comment: maybe obvious, maybe not: if the float numbers you are using all fall inside a certain range and you only care about certain number of significant digits then you can map them to integers without loss. Integers as keys are no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can round trip a number with `DBL_DIG` significant digits or fewer via a `std::string`. Typically `DBL_DIG` is 15 but that depends on the floating point scheme used on your platform.

That's not *quite* the same as what you are asking. For example, it's possible on some platforms to change the floating point rounding mode at runtime, so you could end up with different results even during the execution of a program. Then you have signed zeros, subnormal numbers, and NaN (in its various guises) to worry about.

There are just too many pitfalls. I would not be comfortable using floating point types as map keys. It would be far, far better to use the `std::string` as the key in your map.

Comment: wouldn't std::string be slower as map key?

Comment: @ArsenZahray: Race it. Note you're using an unordered map, so it's really down to the string hash.

Comment: @ArsenZahray I hope you're not talking about `std::unordered_map`, because that one is excruciatingly slow by itself in most implementations. A possible alternative is `dense_hash_map`.

Comment: @rustyx actually, I'm talking about tsl::robin_map. last time I checked, it looked good in benchmarks